# How to set inventory details when creating item receipt with client script 2.0?

Tags: netsuite

I tried to get sublist subrecord from line item of item receipt record, but its return null.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/error', 'N/currentRecord'],
  function (error, currentRecord) {
    function pageInit(context) {
      var rec = currentRecord.get();
      rec.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: 0 });
      var inventoryDetailSubRecord = rec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'inventorydetail' });
      // inventoryDetailSubRecord object comes up with null.
    }

    return {
      pageInit: pageInit
    };
  }
);
```

inventoryDetailSubRecord object should come up with inventory detail subrecord.

Answer (score 2):

Client scripts can read subrecords, but they can't write to them. `getCurrentSublistSubrecord` creates the sub-record if it doesn't exist.

From the docs;

> A client script may not create subrecords on the current record and is limited to read-only access of existing subrecords on the current record. The client script may remove the subrecord from the current record.